# Is there a standard name registrar contract?

Tags: name-registrar

In Etherscan's [accounts](https://etherscan.io/accounts) page, some accounts have names affiliated with them. Where are these names saved? I'm thinking of making a name registry for my dapp, but I would like to know if there is a "global" one that I can use instead.

Thanks,

Comment: It used to be that they were manually added by Etherscan, not served. I'm suspecting this is still the case. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/how-can-i-add-my-name-next-to-address-on-etherscan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ENS](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/137) is a planned, official name registration system. It is currently only on the testnet, but I believe it was announced at EDCON that it is intended to be released on the mainnet on March 14 of this year.