# Custom name to smart contract

Tags: contract-development, etherscan

I have seen that some smart contracts (not tokens) have a text name in etherscan. Is it possible to add it to my contract? How I could do it?

I have try to add a public variable "name" but it is not worked.

For example ZRXTokenContract:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xe41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498

Comment: Basically a duplicate of: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/how-can-i-add-my-name-next-to-address-on-etherscan

Comment: It was a year ago, at that moment only a few accounts have names. But now just every smart contract have his own name. Is the process not changed? And I have not see any messages with name and site link to any contract in comments section (as it suggested in answer), but they have own name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit their [Feedback Page](https://etherscan.io/contactus):

1. Make sure that your token contract's source code has been properly ***verified*** on their site.
2. Provide them with your contract's address.
3. Provide them with your website's url.
4. Provide them with a link to download your 28x28 PNG icon/logo.

Then wait... There's no guarantee that they'll add your info to their ***private*** database.