# Why are ERC20 tokens displayed differently on Etherscan?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, etherscan

I've noticed that tokens are displayed slightly differently on Etherscan.

When you are on an address and click on the dropdown to see the tokens, some appear as an address, and some appear as a name:

[image]

This is how the Token "Titanium BAR" is displayed:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xc7579bb99af590ec71c316e1ac4436c535039594

[image]

And on some other tokens, you have "ERC-20 Token" instead of "Token" written on the token page:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xfa74f89a6d4a918167c51132614bbbe193ee8c22
[image]

So, do you have an idea why it is like that, and does it have something to do with the validation process on Etherscan?

Thank you!

*ps: already found this hint [How Can I Add My Name Next To Address On Etherscan?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/how-can-i-add-my-name-next-to-address-on-etherscan) - not sure if it is the right path though*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you pointed out, this has to do with Etherscan's validation process, as explained in the link that you have supplied, you can request that the name be added and they ask you to provide them several details, logos, etc and then its up to them to do it, with no guarantee when this will happen or even if it will happen at all.

Furthermore, this is not related to the token being compliant to ERC20 or not, as the token that you used as an example (Titanium BAR) is in fact ERC20 too, as you can see from its [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc7579bb99af590ec71c316e1ac4436c535039594#code).